# Reverse key value array in JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json, function

I have a key value array in php like this

```
[1]=>"something"
[2]=>"somethingelse"
[4]=>"this"
```

Now i would like to export this as json, reverse the array, but keep the indexes. So the json format would look something like

```
{
    "4":"this",
    "2":"somethingelse"
    "1":"something"
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this (without parsing the json manually)?

Comment: use array_reverse() function and then json_encode() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reverse = array_reverse($array, true);
$json = json_encode ($reverse);
```

Comment: Thanks (to the rest as well), array_reverse did the trick altough my json browser extension made me believe it didn't by sorting the array. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

#### You need to preserve the keys in the `array_reverse` to get this working.

```
<?php
$arr=array(1=>"something",2=>"somethingelse",4=>"this");
echo json_encode(array_reverse($arr,true),true);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
{"4":"this","2":"somethingelse","1":"something"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_flip()](http://php.net/array_flip) for this.

```
$array = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two');

$arrayFlipped = array_flip($array);

/*
$arrayFlipped:

Array
(
   [one] => 1
   [two] => 2
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to reverse the order of the array, it's best to do so before conversing it to JSON. You can do this using the [`array_reverse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function, you will need to set the second parameter to `TRUE` to preserve the indexes.

```
<?php
$myArray = Array(
    1 => "something",
    2 => "somethingelse",
    4 => "this"
);

$myJSON = json_encode( array_reverse( $myArray, true ) );

print_r( $myJSON );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
    1 => "something",
    2 => "somethingelse",
    4 => "this"
);

$arr = array_reverse($arr,true); // true!

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [array_reverse](http://pk1.php.net/array_reverse)

`Example:`

```
$arr = array("apple","banana","orange");
$reversed = array_reverse($arr,true);
echo json_encode($reversed);
```